# How can I pick an random value from a list of options and replace that value in another list? Details below:

Tags: python, random, replace

So, the program works just fine, but even after incorporating that last modification suggested by abarnert, it still won't make sure to generate a unique mutation.

This is what I've got so far. I'm sure it's not right, but I don't fully understand how python executes the code written by abarnert below.

```
a = open (scgenome, 'r')

codon = [ ] 

for line in a:

    data=line.split("\t") 

    codon.append(data[12]) 

import random 

def string_replace(s,index,char):
    return s[:index] + char + s[index+1:]


for x in range(1,1000):
   index = random.randrange(3)
   letter_to_replace = random.choice(list({"A", "G", "T", "C"} - {codon[index]}))
   mutated_codon = [string_replace(codon[x], index, letter_to_replace)]
       for c in mutated_codon: 
             codon_lookup[c]
```

I have also tried to write this your way without using range, although I like using the range function so that I can print out 10 or 100 codons and manually check if the output is correct, but then I get a Keyerror: 'r', which didn't occur before when i ran this program before trying to make sure that each substitution is unique:

```
def string_replace(s,index,char):

    return s[:index] + char + s[index+1:]



def mutate_codon(codon):

  index = random.randrange(3)

  letter_to_replace = random.choice(list({"A", "G", "T", "C"} - {codon[index]}))

  return string_replace(codon, index, letter_to_replace)



 for codon in codons:
   codons = mutate_codon(codon)

   print codons 

   for c in codons:

      codon_lookup[c]

      if codon_lookup[c] == ref_aminoacid[x]:

           print codons, "\t", codon_lookup[c]

      else: 

          print codons, "\t", codon_lookup[c]
```

Comment: what do you have so far? what have you tried? what if you get rid of the random element could you do it then? (put the answers in the original question (with edit), dont post a comment with the answers to those questions.)

Comment: So far, this is what I've done: mylist = ["A", "G", "T", "C"]

from random import choice 

print choice(mylist)  Even after that, I think the more difficult part is to figure out how to get the program to pick a letter from a given string.

Comment: `import random; random.choice("XYZABC")` will get you that far

Comment: You should study the `random` module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

Comment: I don't understand. What you've got so far sounds like exactly what you said you didn't know how to do…

Comment: Just figured out how to pick at random.

Comment: Now that you've posted some code, a couple of minor side notes, then some bigger ones separately: You don't need to keep track of `idnum` like that; it's just `len(codon)`. Meanwhile, any loop that just does an `append` to an empty list can be rewritten as a list comprehension. Naming your list `codon` is confusing; it's each _element_ of that list that's a codon, not the whole thing.

Comment: `for x in range(1, idnum)` skips the first codon, because Python lists are 0-based, not 1-based. Also, your problem definition said you wanted to apply the same mutation to all of the codons, but your code picks a _different_ `letter_to_replace` for each one. As I explained in my answer, `codon[index_to_replace] = letter_to_replace` won't work because strings are immutable; that's why I created that `string_replace` function for you.

Comment: Also, you've confused yourself by using the name `codon` for the list of codons; you don't want to replace a whole codon with `letter_to_replace`, but one letter _within_ the codon. That is (using your existing names and structure): `codon[x] = string_replace(codon[x], index_to_replace, letter_to_replace)`.

Comment: And finally, you don't want to re-define the `string_to_replace` function each time through the loop. Plus, you have to define it before you call it. So move it up to the top of the string.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! the reason I selected (1,idnum), instead of 0, is because in the txt file, the first row is just headers and doesn't contain any codons. Secondly, I apologize for the misunderstanding, but I don't want to replace the same mutation in all codons; I want it to select a random mutation for each codon it runs through in order to simulate an environment where the point mutations are totally random and not biased by any factors.

Comment: One last thing I want to add: Now that I have a list of randomly mutated codons, I want to see if these mutations resulted in a synonymous (same amino acid compared to initial) or non-synonymous (different amino acid). Obv. I have to create a list of all possible codons for a given amino acid and compare ALL these lists for each mutated codon and output the amino acid that the mutated codon corresponds to, but that means I have to have 20 if statements, to compare to 20 amino acids. I'm sure there must be a more straightforward method to do this...any ideas? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @user2905511: OK, in that case, just put the `random.choice(['A', 'C', 'G', 'T'])` expression directly into the loop or list comprehension instead of doing it once and storing the result in `letter_to_replace` before the loop/comprehension.

Comment: @user2905511: Meanwhile, if you want to use a file as an iterable of lines, but skip the first line, an idiomatic way to do that is to write `next(f) # skip first line`. However, you may want to consider using the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module once your CSV parsing gets at all complicated.

Comment: @user2905511: For the last bit: You really should create a new question for this if you can't figure it out. But here's a hint that may be sufficient: Think about data structures. With a set of amino acids, the `in` operator tells you whether yours is in the set in one line. With a list of them, the `index` function tells you _where_ yours is in the list. A `dict` can hold a mapping of codons to amino acids, so you don't need 64 if statements, just one. And so on.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I still can't figure out how it would work because, first it must go through a list of codons, then it must figure out which amino acid that codon corresponds to. However, i don't see a way around creating a list for every single amino acid b/c there are multiple codons with each amino acid. Perhaps I don't understand dictionaries too well, so I'm not sure how to map codons to AAs in a given dictionary. Here's the link to this separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802024/how-can-i-do-the-following-comparison-without-having-to-write-20-if-statements-o

Comment: @abarnert I could use some help with part of my initial question. If the random mutation happens to mutate the same position with the same amino acid, it will result in the same codon as before. I want the program to run through as many times as necessary for a given codon until the result is different from the initial codon. How can I do this? the comparison can be done with an 'if' statement, but how can I make the program return to the random choice instead of moving to the next codon on the list?

Comment: @user2905511: For the separate question, I'll go look at that. For the last followup, let me edit my answer again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function [`random.choice`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) picks a random element from a sequence. So:

```
letter_to_replace = random.choice(['A', 'C', 'G', 'T'])
```

To pick a letter from a given codon, you really want to pick an *index* at random—0, 1, or 2. (After all, for the codon `'AAA'`, you presumably want to be able to replace any of the three `'A'` characters, right?) For that, use `random.randrange(3)`:

```
for codon in codons:
    index_to_replace = random.randrange(3)
    codon[index_to_replace] = letter_to_replace
```

Except that if each `codon` is a string, of course, you can't mutate it in-place, so you need a function like this:

```
def string_replace(s, index, char):
    return s[:index] + char + s[index+1:]
```

What we're doing here is building a new string out of slices: `s[:index]` is all of the characters from the start to the `index`th (remember that Python slicing is half-open: `s[i:j]` includes `i`, `i+1`, …, `j-1`, but not `j`), and `s[index+1]` is all of the characters from the `index+1`th to the end. So, this is everything before `index`, `char` in place of whatever was in `index`, and then everything after `index`. This is described in detail in the [Strings](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) section of the tutorial (with a bit of followup in the Lists section of the same chapter).

And while you're already doing things immutably:

```
codons = [string_replace(codon, random.randrange(3), letter_to_replace)
          for codon in codons]
```

This uses a list comprehension: instead of modifying the list of codons in-place, we build a new list of codons. [List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in the tutorial explains how these work, but a simple example may help:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2 * element for element in a]
assert b == [2, 4, 6, 8]

c = []
for element in a:
    c.append(2 * element)
assert c == b
```

You can also filter the list as you build it with `if` clauses, nest multiple `for` clauses together, build a `set` or `dict`, or a lazy generator, instead of a `list`… see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#list-displays) for full details.

---

Here's how to put it all together, with a few other fixes (using a `with` to make sure the file gets closed, and some of the stuff I commented on the question):

```
# Read the codons into a list
with open(scgenome) as f:
    codons = [line.split('\t')[12] for line in f]

# Create a new list of mutated codons
def string_replace(s, index, char):
    return s[:index] + char + s[index+1:]
letter_to_replace = random.choice(['A', 'C', 'G', 'T'])
codons = [string_replace(codon, random.randrange(3), letter_to_replace)
          for codon in codons]
```

---

If you want to guarantee a single point mutation in each codon, and you don't need each one to mutate to the same base, you need to rethink things a little. For each codon, pick one of the three positions. Then, instead of picking randomly from all four bases, pick from all of the bases *except* the one that's already there. So:

```
def string_replace(s, index, char):
    return s[:index] + char + s[index+1:]

def mutate_codon(codon):
    index = random.randrange(3)        
    new_base = random.choice(list({'A', 'C', 'T', 'G'} - {codon[index]}))
    return string_replace(codon, index, new_base)

codons = [mutate_codon(codon) for codon in codons]
```

If that function line is confusing, let me explain: Sets have a nice `-` operator that computes the set difference—that is, all values in the left set that aren't also in the right set. `{'A', 'C', 'T', 'G'} - {'T'}` is `{'A', 'C', 'G'}`. So, I take the set of all four bases, subtract out the one that's already at `codon[index]`, and randomly choose any of the other three. Since `choice` only works on sequences, I have to make a list out of the set.

You could, of course, rewrite this to use a list (or even str) in the first place, but then you have to write the "list difference" manually. Not a big deal:

```
new_base = random.choice([base for base in codon if base != codon[index]])
```

Comment: just curious? why did you use an index instead of another random choice?

Comment: I am not sure of OP's intent, but I would guess he might want to check whether the old and new char are same, in that case OP can compare

Comment: @JoranBeasley: How would you use `random.choice` here? If the codon is, say, `'AAA'`, that'll just give you `'A'`, which isn't very useful. (Of course you could use `choice(enumerate(codon))`, but given that you only need the index, not the value, it doesn't really add anything.)

Comment: I dunno I read his question as wanting to replace one character with another "AAA" replace "A" with "T" becomes "TTT" .... but I could have easily misunderstood his intent ... basically I was thinking `codon =codon.replace(choice(codon),replace_with_char)`

Comment: @ Joran Beasley, for sure he does not want to replace all the instance of "A", just one of three (I happen to know what these thing are), and depending upon what he wants, he might actually want to replace with other three.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: The fact that he wants to replace "any one of those three letters", and repeats the same thing in different words, makes me pretty confident that he doesn't want to turn`"AAA"` into `"TTT"`, but rather `"TAA"` or `"ATA"` or `"AAT"` (with an equal chance of each).

Comment: alright :) gotcha :) it just wasnt clear from the question and Ive forgotten most of my bioinformatics stuff... with that information the choice to use an index instead of a choice is very clear :)

Comment: Abarnert and Ananta, you are both correct. I realize that some people don't know what codons are, so it's difficult to explain. Abarnert, just a few questions about your suggested script:  Can you please explain how the last 2 sets of statements you wrote actually work? I'm not sure what the general syntax is for the last 2 sets of statements, so I have no idea how they work. I get the rest. I am about to update my initial question with what I've got so far, so please check it out. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @user2905511: OK, I'll update the answer with a brief explanation and some links.

Comment: Thanks! What do I have to modify what I have written so far in my script?

Comment: I'm unsure of how to incorporate the last line "codons = " into my script.

Comment: @user2905511: That one line replaces your whole loop. (And then you put the `string_replace` function somewhat at the top of your script.) You've called the list of codons `codon` instead of `codons`, so you'll need to rename things slightly to make it work (maybe `one_codon in codon` instead of `codon in codons`)… although I think naming the list plural makes more sense.

Comment: I'm still not understanding your script. Probably because of the way you named things and the following loop : for codon in codons. What does that mean? codons is not defined. Can you edit my script to demonstrate what you said in your previous comment? I'm still a bit confused on how this should be organized.

Comment: @user2905511: Did you read my last comment? It explains exactly what you're asking about: You named your list of codons `codon` instead of `codons`. Besides being confusing, this means you have to use `codon` everywhere I used `codons`, and use a different name like `one_codon` everywhere I used `codon`.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for the edit! I have tried incorporating the modification but I get the following error:  letter_to_replace = random.choice({"A", "G", "T", "C"} - {codon[index]})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 274, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing

Comment: @user2905511: Sorry, it looks like `random.choice` needs a sequence, not just an iterable. Change it to `random.choice(list(…))`; I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @abarnert Hey, I edited my initial question with what I've got now and the program still runs, but it doesn't do what I expected it. Unfortunately, I don't fully understand the way you have written the script, but if you could please help me out with the same variables that I used to write it, that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @user2905511: If you have a further problem, don't try to edit your original question into a followup. When you do things this way, only one person will see your new question, instead of the entire community. It also makes your question much less useful to anyone finding it in a search, prevents you from getting any reputation or accept-rate for the question, and has all kinds of other negatives. Just create a new question, with a link to this one.

Comment: @abarnert   Ya, sorry about that. I just did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106649/how-can-i-modify-the-following-program-so-that-i-can-make-sure-that-each-letter

Comment: @abarnert I applaud you for making a answer this long for a non-major question.