# How can I do the following comparison without having to write 20 if-statements or making 20 lists/dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This problem is related to biology, so for those who know what amino acids and codons are, that's great! For those who don't, I have tried my best to phrase it so that you can understand what I am talking about.

So I have a list of codons, also can be called 3-letter strings, that are composed of a combination of the following four letters: A, G, C, T i.e. AAT, GAT, GCT, etc. Each codon corresponds to a particular amino acid, but there are multiple codons that can correspond to the same amino acid. To illustrate this, please take a look at this link: http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/courses/27619/codon.html. That should make it clear.

For each codon on my list, I want to ultimately find out which amino acid it corresponds to. Therefore, I must make the program first compare that codon to the list of codons (64 total possible codons) that I posted the link for, and then I have to ask the program to see which amino acid that codon corresponds to. However, I  can't figure out a shortcut method of doing this without having to make a list for all codons that correspond to a given amino acid and compare them, or write 20 different if statements.

The list of codons I have is called mutated_codon. So, I will need to generate a 'for' where the program compares each codon on my mutated_codon list and compares it to the dictionary and outputs the corresponding Amino acid letter. What is the code that I have to write to do that? I'm not familiar with the syntax used to check for values in a dictionary.

Here's what I've go so far based on suggestions:

> codon_lookup = {'GCT': 'A', 'GCC': 'A','GCA': 'A','GCG': 'A', 'TGT': 'C','TGC':'C', 'GAT':'D','GAC': 'D', 'GAA':'E','GAG': 'E', 'TTT':'F','TTC': 'F', 'GGT': 'G','GGC': 'G','GGA':'G','GGG': 'G', 'CAT':'H','CAC': 'H', 'ATT':'I','ATC':'I','ATA':'I','AAA':'K','AAG':'K', 'TTA': 'L','TTG': 'L','CTT': 'L','CTC': 'L','CTA': 'L','CTG': 'L', 'ATG': 'M', 'AAT':'N','AAC':'N', 'CCT': 'P','CCC': 'P','CCA': 'P','CCG': 'P', 'CAA': 'Q','CAG': 'Q', 'CGT': 'R','CGC': 'R','CGA': 'R','CGG': 'R','AGA': 'R','AGG': 'R', 'TCT': 'S','TCC': 'S','TCA': 'S','TCG': 'S','AGT': 'S','AGC': 'S', 'ACT': 'T','ACC': 'T','ACA': 'T','ACG': 'T', 'GTT': 'V','GTC': 'V','GTA': 'V','GTG': 'V', 'TGG' = 'W', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAC':'Y', 'TAA': 'Z', 'TAG': 'Z', 'TGA':'Z'}

```
for c in mutated_codon:
   print codon_lookup[c]
```

HOwever, in my output I only get output for the amino acid that corresponds to the last codon on the list, and on top of that, I get KeyError: 4. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Please update your question with a sample of input and output or any code you have written.

Comment: You just need one dictionary that maps codons to amino acids.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not very experienced with making dictionaries, so it would be helpful if you can provide me with an exapmle of how that could be done for one or two amino acids.

Comment: I was going to, but farmerjoe beat me to it.

Comment: In addition to the answers showing how to set up the dictionary, you might find value in the biopython third party library. For this question,  bio.seq.translate translates a sequence of nucleotides into amino acid code letters.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Oh wow, I didn't know about that. That sounds super helpful. So I just write my code in bipython and use bio.seq.translate in my loop so that it translates each codon into its corresponding AA?

Comment: Pretty much. It expects a string of nucleotide symbols or one of its sequence classes, so you'd have to create one from your list of mutated codons but that shouldn't be hard. I'm posting from a phone now, I might post an example later. The dict answers are good, btw - thinking with dicts is important in python.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Yep. Since I have most of the code written, I'm not going to swtich to biopython now, but it might be useful in the future. I am having trouble with the code though, check the last bit of my question (I edited it). Thanks!!

Comment: Do you need acids printed, or do you need a list of the acids? Or a string of symbols?

Comment: I need the amino acid letters printed. So if the mutated_codon is TAA, then I want to print TAA - Z (I have denoted Z for a stop codon). If AAG is Leucine, then I want to print AAG - L

Comment: I tried typing in  print codon_lookup[mutated_codon], but I get the following error - TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @user2905511: It sounds like you're confusing yourself with your names again. You're using `mutated_codon` as the name for the list of all of the codons, not for a single codon. You can look up `mutated_codon[0]`, or `for codon in mutated_codon: print codon_lookup[codon]` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering just to address the question on how to look up the protein from the dictionary. Correctly creating the dictionary is the core of your problem, and the answers given so far address that well. I personally like FogleBird's reverse construction best, but any of the ways to define a dictionary mapping nucleotide symbol triples to amino acids will work fine.

Given the `codon_lookup` dictionary as you define it in your edit to the question and a list of three-letter strings named `mutated_codon`, the simplest way to print the amino acid symbols from a list of mutated codons would be this:

```
for codon in mutated_codon:
    print codon_lookup[codon]
```

Or, in Python 3.X:

```
for codon in mutated_codon:
    print(codon_lookup[codon])
```

It would be more in keeping with the usual Python style to name the list `mutated_codons`, since it will almost certainly be plural, but that's not a big deal. I'll proceed with `mutated_codon` below.

If I were writing this code, I would probably derive a list of the amino acids for the mutated codons, and possibly print or do other things on that list. The simplest way to do that is using a list comprehension to define a new list:

```
acids = [codon_lookup[codon] for codon in mutated_codon]
```

This is more or less syntactic sugar for a for loop that builds the new list:

```
acids = []
for codon in mutated_codon:
    acids.append(codon_lookup[codon])
```

But it's more concise. I hesitate to describe performance without actually testing the two different versions, but I believe the list comprehension form is also faster.

Either way, I could then iterate over that list to print them:

```
for acid in acids:
    print acid
```

As well as doing any further necessary processing.

One other option worth pointing out is the `get` method on the dictionary. The above code all uses direct key lookup on the dictionary, which will raise a `KeyError` if your codon is not found in the `codon_lookup` dictionary. This is probably the best choice - you're working with a limited range of input, and if something leads to you getting a string that isn't a valid codon in your `mutated_codon` list you probably want to see that exception rather than hiding it. But if in some future situation you're dealing with input that's less controlled, you might find the `get` method useful. This method of a dictionary accepts a key and an optional default value. If the key is in the dictionary, it returns the dictionary's value for that key. If the key is not in the dictionary, it returns the default value (if one was provided) or `None` (if one was not). If, for example, you wanted your code to treat any unknown codon as a stop, you could write something like this:

```
for codon in mutated_codon:
    print codon_lookup.get(codon, '*')
```

And since I earlier mentioned [biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page), here's an example taken from their [docs](http://biopython.org/wiki/Seq#Translation) of using `translate` to convert DNA nucleotides to amino acids:

```
>>> from Bio.Seq import Seq
>>> from Bio.Alphabet import generic_dna
>>> coding_dna = Seq("ATGGCCATTGTAATGGGCCGCTGAAAGGGTGCCCGATAG", generic_dna)
>>> coding_dna.translate()
Seq('MAIVMGR*KGAR*', HasStopCodon(ExtendedIUPACProtein(), '*'))
```

The docs I've linked to have tons more detail. It may be more than you need for this particular task, but it might save you some work if you need to take it further than a simple translation table.

Comment: I have updated my initial quesiton with the code that I am using. I used your first statement suggestion for codon_lookup but the error I get is this - KeyError: 4, and on top of that, i only get codon_lookup for the last codon on my list, rather than for every codon.

Comment: That `KeyError` means you're looking for `4` rather than a codon string in your dictionary. To me, that suggests that `mutated_codon` is not a list of codon strings.

Comment: I figured out what the error was. Fixed it and it works! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 11):

You can set a dictionary up like this:

```
codon_lookup = {
    'ATT':'Isoleucine',
    'ATC':'Isoleucine', 
    'ATA':'Isoleucine',
    'CTT':'Leucine',
    'CTC':'Leucine', 
    'CTA':'Leucine',
     # ... etc
}
```

then you can make queries like

```
codon_lookup['ATT']
```

Which will give you

```
'Isoleucine'
```

**EDIT:**

You can set a dictionary up like this:

```
codon_lookup = {
    'ATT':'I',
    'ATC':'I', 
    'ATA':'I',
    'CTT':'L',
    'CTC':'L', 
    'CTA':'L',
     # ... etc
}
```

then you can make queries like

```
codon_lookup['ATT']
```

Which will give you

```
'I'
```

If you want to check your list of `mutated_condons` against this dictionary you can loop through it like this.  If your `mutated_condons` list looks like `['ACA','GTT',...]` then:

```
for mutated_codon in mutated_condons:
    print codon_lookup[mutated_codon]
```

Comment: There are going to be 44 duplicate amino acid names in the code if this is used.

Comment: @TimothyShields Hey timothy, I actually already wrote the code based on this code. What's wrong with having 44 duplicate amino acid names?

Comment: Also, what is the appropriate way to lookup the value in the dictionary? I have updated by question with the code I've got so far.

Comment: @user2905511 Nothing "wrong" in the sense that your code will work perfectly fine. My disdain was more ideologically driven. See my answer and the comments on for why.

Comment: @TimothyShields Oh I see what you're saying. I suppose your proposed method is definitely more efficient and a 'cleaner' way of doing it, but I was already using this method before I saw your post, so I suppose I"ll just stick to it. Thanks for the input though! What is the appropriate code to look-up values? My list of codons is under a list called mutated_codon, so i want to compare each mutated_codon in my loop to the values in the dictionary.

Comment: @user2905511 I made an edit with an example for looking up condons in your list.

Answer (score 5):

In light of the other two answers, here's another way of structuring it that I think might be best.

This will give you lookup dictionaries in both directions: SLC to Codon(s) and Codon to SLC.

```
slc_codon = {
    'I': ['ATT', 'ATC', 'ATA'],
    'L': ['CTT', 'CTC', 'CTA', 'CTG', 'TTA', 'TTG'],
    'V': ['GTT', 'GTC', 'GTA', 'GTG'],
    'F': ['TTT', 'TTC'],
    'M': ['ATG'],
    'C': ['TGT', 'TGC'],
    'A': ['GCT', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG'],
    'G': ['GGT', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG'],
    'P': ['CCT', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG'],
    'T': ['ACT', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG'],
    'S': ['TCT', 'TCC', 'TCA', 'TCG', 'AGT', 'AGC'],
    'Y': ['TAT', 'TAC'],
    'W': ['TGG'],
    'Q': ['CAA', 'CAG'],
    'N': ['AAT', 'AAC'],
    'H': ['CAT', 'CAC'],
    'E': ['GAA', 'GAG'],
    'D': ['GAT', 'GAC'],
    'K': ['AAA', 'AAG'],
    'R': ['CGT', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'CGG', 'AGA', 'AGG'],
    '*': ['TAA', 'TAG', 'TGA'],
}

codon_slc = dict((x, k) for k, v in slc_codon.items() for x in v)

>>> print codon_slc
>>> {'CTT': 'L', 'ATG': 'M', 'AAG': 'K', 'AAA': 'K', 'ATC': 'I', 'AAC': 'N', 'ATA': 'I', 'AGG': 'R', 'CCT': 'P', 'ACT': 'T', 'AGC': 'S', 'ACA': 'T', 'AGA': 'R', 'CAT': 'H', 'AAT': 'N', 'ATT': 'I', 'CTG': 'L', 'CTA': 'L', 'CTC': 'L', 'CAC': 'H', 'ACG': 'T', 'CAA': 'Q', 'AGT': 'S', 'CAG': 'Q', 'CCG': 'P', 'CCC': 'P', 'TAT': 'Y', 'GGT': 'G', 'TGT': 'C', 'CGA': 'R', 'CCA': 'P', 'TCT': 'S', 'GAT': 'D', 'CGG': 'R', 'TTT': 'F', 'TGC': 'C', 'GGG': 'G', 'TAG': '*', 'GGA': 'G', 'TAA': '*', 'GGC': 'G', 'TAC': 'Y', 'GAG': 'E', 'TCG': 'S', 'TTA': 'L', 'GAC': 'D', 'TCC': 'S', 'GAA': 'E', 'TCA': 'S', 'GCA': 'A', 'GTA': 'V', 'GCC': 'A', 'GTC': 'V', 'GCG': 'A', 'GTG': 'V', 'TTC': 'F', 'GTT': 'V', 'GCT': 'A', 'ACC': 'T', 'TGA': '*', 'TTG': 'L', 'CGT': 'R', 'TGG': 'W', 'CGC': 'R'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write down the table (from the link you gave) exactly as it is:

```
table =
    [
        {
            'amino_acid': 'Isoleucine',
            'codons': [ 'ATT', 'ATC', 'ATA' ]
        },
        {
            'amino_acid': 'Leucine',
            'codons': [ 'CTT', 'CTC', 'CTA', 'CTG', 'TTA', 'TTG' ]
        },
        ...etc...
    ]
```

Then use the following to transform to a dictionary that maps from codon to amino acid:

```
lookup = dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    [[(codon, row['amino_acid']) for codon in row['codons']] for row in table]))
```

For example, `lookup['TTA']` gives `'Leucine'`.

I feel this is slightly more elegant than repeating the amino acid names, as in farmerjoe's answer, but that may be a matter of opinion. Better to do data entry in the most concise possible way then transform it programatically than to manually transform it by hand.

Comment: Even nicer would be to just copy over the table from the web to a text file and build the dict from that. This should be really easy if you replace all the `','` with whitespace.

Comment: @moarningsun Absolutely. If you view page source of `http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/courses/27619/codon.html` you'll see that the data is already neatly packaged in HTML format for you to use. Just pull out the part for the table, stick it in a file, then read the data directly from that file.

Comment: making a dict from itertools.chain.fromiterable from a nested list comprehension of grouped data is only more elegant for a python exert.  Python is great in it's approachability by domain experts vs python programmers.  I can's vote this down because there is elegance but not much simplicity. The @farmerjoe is also akin to how data like this comes from a database.

Comment: @TimothyShields: I wouldn't say _neatly_ packaged; that's clearly either a table that was hand-made in a word processor instead of a text editor, or the output of some 90s-vintage tool… but it's still neat enough to handle without too much hackery. See my answer. And I agree with you that this is a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Picking up Timothy Shields' comment on his own answer, it would be nice if you could just grab the table from http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/courses/27619/codon.html and generate your mapping out of that.

If you try to copy the table from the web page and paste it as a literal string in your source code, you'll see a few problems. First, different browsers have different ideas for how to copy tables. More seriously, the table is written very irregularly; some columns have no newlines, some have one, some have two, and some even have space after the newline. This is going to be very hard to parse.

But, if you take the HTML source, it's a lot easier. Not as easy as it *should* be (the page is a mess, with no IDs or names anywhere, and old-fashioned HTML styling instead of CSS, and so on), but it's immediately clear that the values you want are exactly the table columns, except without the box table at the top, the box header, and the footer. So, here's an example of how you could do that with [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). (It would be a little more verbose if you need to stick to the standard library, but not that much harder.)

```
import urllib2
import bs4

url='http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/courses/27619/codon.html'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page)
codon_lookup = {}
for row in soup.find_all('tr')[2:-1]:
    amino, slc, codons = (col.text.strip() for col in row.find_all('td'))
    if slc == 'Stop':
        slc = 'Z'
    for codon in codons.split(','):
        codon_lookup[codon.strip()] = slc
```

Of course in real life, you probably don't want your program to have to go online every time it needs to run. But you can easily have this program save the results to a pickle file (or a JSON file, or whatever else you prefer). Just add these lines:

```
import pickle
with open('codons.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(codon_lookup, f)
```

Now, in your main program, you just start off with:

```
with open('codons.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    codon_lookup = pickle.load(f)
```