# How can I modify the following program so that I can make sure that each letter it replaces is unique?

Tags: python, string, random

I wrote a program that takes a list of 3-letter strings (also called codons, for those who know biology) and for each string, it will pick any one of the 3 letters (randomly) and will replace that letter with eithe A, G, C, or T (at random). For example: For the string GCT, it will pick any one of the 3 positions at random i.e. C, and then it will randomly change it to either A, G, C, or T i.e. T. So the new string (or codon) generated will be GTT, and so on for the next string on the list.

However, there is one problem. The way I have written it doesn't check to make sure that the new string that it's generating is not the same as the old one. So if the program randomly chooses to change a letter to the same one as initial, then it will output the same string by chance i.e. switching the C from GCT into a C again and producing GCT. I want to make sure this doesn't happen so that the program isn't generating the same string, because this does happen by random chance when analyzing hundreds of thousands of these codons/strings. I tried to do this by using list(A, G, T, C) - codon[index] in the second line of my 'for' loop, but it didn't work.

I won't bother you with the entire code, but initially I just opened the file where my codons/strings are listed (in a column) and appended all of them into a list and named it 'codon'. Here's the remainder:

```
import random 
def string_replace(s,index,char):
return s[:index] + char + s[index+1:]

for x in range(1,10):   # I set the range to 10 so that I can manually check if the program worked properly 
    index = random.randrange(3)
    letter_to_replace = random.choice(list({"A", "G", "T", "C"} - {codon[index]}))
    mutated_codon = [string_replace(codon[x], index, letter_to_replace)]   
    print mutated_codon)
```

Comment: How about a `while` loop?

Comment: @dawg Can you please elaborate on how that would work?

Answer (score 2):

```
- {codon[index]
```

-->  this will be a 3 letter code if codon is a list of 3 letter strings
think you want codon[x][index]

Comment: +1 I think this is it: your current approach seems fine to me, except for the small issue tolanj mentioned.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Thanks for the input. I incorporated that change but there's a small problem. When I manually check the output, the program works as supposed to for most of the codons but for one of them, the output was the same as the initial string, but for the string immediately following that one on the list, it switched 2 letters from that string instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

edit function, to have your codonset there, rather then down, give indexes to replace there,
I don't know how you will create list of codons, but here I have one example

```
listofcodons=["ATC", "AGT", "ACC"]
for s in listofcodons:
    index=random.randrange(3)
    mutated=string_replace(s,index)
    print mutated


def string_replace(s,index):
        codonset=set(["A","C","G","T"])
        toreplace=s[index]
        #codonset.pop(toreplace)
        codonset.remove(toreplace)            
        char=random.choice(codonset)
        return s[:index] + char + s[index+1:]
```

Comment: There are other ways you could do it, but I think this is probably one of the clearer approaches. Although you mean `codonset.remove(toreplace)` rather than `pop` - `pop` doesn't accept an argument.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to enter mutated = string_replace(s, index) into a for loop so that it goes through each string? When I try to do that, it doesn't work because it says "name 's' is not defined".

Comment: @bioprogammer, well, yes I thought you would figure out those things, So, this works with string of codonsets, and you will loop on that list of codon.

Comment: This function would need to be applied to each 3-letter codon, yes. A for loop is one way to do that.

Comment: look edit on where that s comes from, it is inside loop of list of codons

Comment: @Ananta Now it says, string_replace() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: hmm, should not , it only has two, s and index, try again, copy my code again

Answer (score 1):

So I was bored and decided to code golf it (could be shorter but was satisfied here).

```
from random import choice as c
a=['ACT','ATT','GCT'] # as many as you want
f=lambda s,i:s[:i]+c(list(set(['A','G','C','T'])-set(s[i])))+s[i+1:]
b=[f(s,c([0,1,2]))for s in a]
print b
```

`a` can be your list of codons and `b` will be a list of codons with a random index replaced by a random (never the same) letter.

Ok to answer your new question:

```
from random import choice as c
codons = ['ACT','ATT','GCT']
f=lambda s,i:s[:i]+c(list(set(['A','G','C','T'])-set(s[i])))+s[i+1:]
mutated_codons = [f(s,c([0,1,2]))for s in codons]

for codon in mutated_codons:
try:
    print codon, codon_lookup[codon]
except KeyError, e:
    print e
```

Assuming your dictionary is called `condon_lookup`, this will print each mutated codon followed by its amino acid lookup. Your old code was looping over the letters in each mutated codon instead of looping through a list of codons like you intended.

Comment: There's another problem. Each of these codons corresponds to a particular letter that represents an amino acid. I previously made a dictionary for it so that the program can compare each new codon, b, to this dictionary and see which amino acid that codon corresponds to. But when I try to look it up on the dictionary, i get KeyError: r.                                     Here's what I wrote: from random import choice as c
f=lambda s,i:s[:i]+c(list(set(['A','G','C','T'])-set(s[i])))+s[i+1:]
for s in codons:
 mutated_codon = f(s,c([0,1,2]))
 for d in mutated_codon:
  codon_lookup[d]

Comment: what does you dictionary look like?

Comment: odon_lookup = {'GCT': 'A', 'GCC': 'A','GCA': 'A','GCG': 'A', 'TGT':'C','TGC':'C', 'GAT':'D','GAC': 'D', 'GAA':'E','GAG': 'E', 'TTT':'F','TTC': 'F', 'GGT': 'G','GGC': 'G','GGA':'G','GGG': 'G', 'CAT':'H','CAC': 'H', 'ATT':'I','ATC':'I','ATA':'I','AAA':'K','AAG':'K', 'TTA': 'L','TTG': 'L','CTT': 'L','CTC': 'L','CTA': 'L','CTG': 'L', 'ATG': 'M', 'AAT':'N','AAC':'N', 'CCT': 'P','CCC': 'P','CCA': 'P','CCG': 'P', 'CAA': 'Q','CAG': 'Q', 'CGT': 'R','CGC': 'R','CGA': 'R','CGG': 'R','AGA': 'R','AGG': 'R', 'TCT': 'S','TCC': 'S','TCA': 'S','TCG': 'S','AGT': 'S','AGC': 'S', 'ACT': 'T','ACC': 'T'}

Comment: thanks for the edit. However, for some reason I get keyerror: 'G'. I know keyerrors result when the program can't find it in the dictionary, but I know my dictionary is comprehensive and it includes all possibilities of codons that could be generated, so why the error?

Comment: @bioprogrammer edit your main post to have all of your current code so I can help further, look at my edit where I added a try except block. See what happens. KeyError: 'G' sounds like one of the items in your mutated_codons is 'G' instead of a three letter string. This may be due to your original codons list having an error.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop:

```
import random

mutated_codon=codon='GCT'

while mutated_codon==codon:
    li=list(mutated_codon)
    li[random.choice([0,1,2])]=random.choice(["A", "G", "T", "C"]) 
    mutated_codon = ''.join(li) 

print codon, mutated_codon
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import random

def yield_mutated_codons(codon):
    possible_set = set({"A", "G", "T", "C"})

    for x in range(1, 10):
        index = random.randrange(3)
        letter_to_replace = codon[index]
        current_set = possible_set - set(letter_to_replace)
        codon[index] = random.choice(list(current_set))
        yield ''.join(codon)

def main():
    codon = list('GAT')

    for mutated_codon in yield_mutated_codons(codon):
        print(mutated_codon)

main()
```